# How to mock spring injected classes using JMockit

Tags: java, spring, junit, mocking, jmockit

My code:

```
class A extends X {
    @Autowired
    B b;

    @Override
    method() {
        //do something
        b.callMethodInB;
        //do something
    }

}

class B extends X {
    @Autowired
    C c;

    @Override
    method() {
        //do something
        c.callMethodInC;
       //do something
    }

}
```

I need to test `method()` in `A`. So how to mock `B`. I'm using Junit4 and Jmockit.

Comment: Are you asking how to mock B, or how to inject the mock B into A in your tests?

Answer (score 9):

Try something like this:

```
import org.junit.*;
import mockit.*;

public class ATest
{
    @Tested A a;
    @Injectable B b;

    @Test
    public void testMethod()
    {
        a.method();

        new Verifications() {{ b.callMethodInB(); }};
    }
}
```

JMockit automatically instantiates `A` with an injected `B` instance (from the mock field `b`), setting it to the `a` field in the test class. This is independent of the DI framework used (Spring).

Comment: This did **not** work for me, neither `@Mocked B b;` worked.. on jmockit 1.30

Answer (score 0):

Since Mocking Frameworks usually depends on DI (Dependency Injection), which basically means you need to transfer the mocked object in the method signature, I'm not sure it is possible.

But take a look [here](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home), it might give you a direction on how to do it.